# Prevent Bulletins from following the White Rabbit

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, collectives

Please do something about the size of the Bulletin headers in Collectives. The header takes about 1/3 of the viewport on any decently-sized monitor.

[image: screenshot of a Bulletin from a Collective with an enormous header]

[image: screenshot of another Bulletin with an enormous header]

While we are at it, please fix the sizing of the actions strip that currently has only one "share" button:

[image: screenshot of the actions strip spanning nearly the whole of the viewport width]

---

<sub>Title reference: Jefferson Airplane, [White Rabbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANNqr-vcx0) lyrics</sub>

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. As we work on refining some of the design elements for Bulletins (and Collectives in general) we'll create a pill to make the Bulletin titles smaller.

Comment: Not posted in the Qt, (and not very easy to find), here is [the Link to the Bulletin](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/twilio/bulletins/72639110/online-event-transform-together-building-impact-together-myths-opportunitie)... Header is HUGE indeed, ah-ah...! (Is even bigger "in real" on the Page itself than on the Screenshots...)

Comment: @Berthold thanks! Just don't make the bill that makes them larger, ok? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like we were a bit too eager in making sure our Bulletin titles were noticed. We've reduced the size of the title to a more... reasonable size

[image: desktop view of a Twilio bulletin]

[image: mobile view of a Twilio bulletin]